# Prefetch mapped task object value

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, prefect

I have a prefetch flow with below tasks:

```
def ExecuteFlow():
    emp_ids = get_ids(
        host=,
        user=,
        password=,
    )
    leader_ids = get_leaders.map(
        emp_id=emp_ids,
        host=,
        user=,
        password=,
        upstream_tasks=[emp_ids]
    )

    if leader_ids != 'ABC123':
        next_task()
    else:
        raise exception
```

How do I get the value from the task, the if block is not working since leader_ids is an object and not a list or a boolean.

Comment: What is the return data type of `get_leaders` function?